# How to Retrieve <Value> from a List after doing lgrouping

Tags: c#, grouping

May I know how to I display fields in my `Customer` class after an `lgrouping`, and is the `<Value>` parameter in the output?

```
List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>();                   

foreach (var customer in customerList.GroupBy(x => x.Age))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age: " + customer.Key);

    //Display fields in customer.Value
}
```

---

```
class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Age{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you need read the CustomerId and the Age property object into the loop?

Comment: I will need to retrieve all `CustomerId` in the list, and place them into another list

Comment: `foreach (var customer...)`. `customer` is not a `Customer` (wrong variable name, better change in `foreach (var group in ...)`), is an `IGrouping.` Just iterate the grouping. In the iteration, each member is a `Customer` object.

Comment: Change "var customer " in foreach into something else first, it is confusing. i.e. customerMapElement. then in the loop, customerMapElement.key is Age (grouping factor) and customerMapElement.value is your sub list: IGrouping<customer> . so you have to further iterate that sub list. then you can access fields of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modification of your code:

```
foreach (var customerMapElement in customers.GroupBy(x => x.Age))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Age: " + customerMapElement.Key);
            foreach (var customer in customerMapElement)
                 Console.WriteLine("Customer: " + customer.CustomerId);

            //Display fields in customer.Value
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you must add a foreach into your foreach sinc customer in your code is a list, and in lin

```
var customer in customerList.GroupBy(x => x.Age)
```

The **customer** in code above becomes a list, so you have to use foreach to use the data inside it.
you can use this code below

```
           List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>() {
                new Customer() {CustomerId=1,Age=10}, 
                new Customer() {CustomerId=2,Age=20},
                new Customer() {CustomerId=3,Age=20},
                new Customer() {CustomerId=4,Age=30},
                new Customer() {CustomerId=5,Age=10},
                };
            foreach (var customer in customerList.GroupBy(x => x.Age))
            {
                foreach (var item in customer)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Age: " + item.Age+" and "+item.CustomerId+"\n");
                }
                
            }
```